# Reading Text Fields in Stack View

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I used the interface builder to make 6 text fields in a vertical stack view. I would like to get the values in each text field preferably neatly in an array. Do I have to create an outlet for each individual text field or can I create one outlet to the stack view and get all the text field values at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating six outlets you can chose to make an `OutletCollection`. Ctrl+Drag the first outlet to your controller, instead of `Outlet`, choose `OutletCollection`:

[image]

After doing so, Ctrl+Drag your other buttons to the `OutletCollection` you just created to hook 'em up!

[image]

You can then loop through the array:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var fields: [UITextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for field in self.fields {
            //Do whatever you want with the fields
        }
    }

}
```